# "Index: 0, Size: 0 View draw error" Android Studio design tab error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I've recently updated my AS to 4.0 version. After that I put an EditText and a TextView inside of my layout, which looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:text="EditText should be below me!"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="I'm a hint"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

However, the design tab doesn't show me the EditText at all!
[image: Design tab without the input field]

At the bottom of the screenshot, you can see error. Googling it didn't help me, everything I found is [Design in Android studio error Index:0 size:0.... View draw failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62384882/design-in-android-studio-error-index0-size0-view-draw-failed) question, which has no answer.

**What I've already done**

I invalidated caches and restarted my AS but it didn't help. Also, I've changed the app's theme from

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

which had no impact. However, once I managed to change it to something like a button element style and it worked, even though it's not the solution I'm looking for. If I explicitly change the style of the EditText to things like

```
@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog
```

or

```
@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless
```

I can see the EditText...

I'll appreciate any help you give me, guys. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**:

It's possible to fix the problem by switching on the "Use new Layout Rendering Engine" in the settings of the AS.

[image: Fix]

Anyway, I hope we're able to find this thing out and fix it, guys. Thank you for your attention!

Comment: it seems fine, can you close, clean build folder and run the app in a different device/emulator

Comment: @notTdar thanks for such a fast reply! It's reaaaaally strange, but once I cleaned it, it started working... Thanks! I will not delete the question, maybe it's helpful for someone.

Comment: @notTdar oops! I fixed it by enabling new layout rendering engine in experimental settings of the AS.... Gonna put the answer here

Comment: it's odd that solved your issue, normally does not happen

Comment: omg that problem came across my device ....